How to set Telegram message font to monospace when using HTTP POST?
I'm using the Telegram API but I'm writing messages via raw HTTP. For example:
POST /bot123:token123/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=hello

How can I change my message to use font monospace?
I couldn't find any advice how to do this using raw HTTP.

It's actually easy. You need to specify the parse_mode parameter and add the formatting style directly in the text parameter.
Here's an example which uses MarkdownV2 parse mode.
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123456&text=`Hello%20World`&parse_mode=MarkdownV2

And here's an example for sending monowidth text with HTML parse mode.
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123456&text=<code>Hello World</code>&parse_mode=HTML


Also, if you're using POST requests it can be written more clearly:
POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>

With the following data:
{
    "chat_id": 123456,
    "text": "<code>Hello World</code>",
    "parse_mode": "HTML"
}


See the Formatting Options section in the Bot API documentation for detailed info on different styles you can use.
Hope this helps.
